# Asterisk pjsip loading all endpoints on startup

Tags: asterisk

Asterisk is loading all mysql reatime endpoints on startup, this is causing pjsip to crash and not accept registrations.  Is there an option in the .conf file i can add to not load the endpoints?

Comment: This is likely a bug in Asterisk.  You should consider reporting it to the Devs.

Answer (score 0):

If you are storing config in database, it read config.

If you use REALTIME(store of peers only in db),it load peers when needed(at least for chan_sip, never tried for pjsip).

Comment: yeh it sounds like it could be a bug.. pjsip seems to load all endpoints on startup to see if still active.

Comment: Not think it is bug. More likly not realized for pjsip channel(it relative new). Use chan_sip if you have plenty of peers.

Comment: chan_sip is  full of bugs and not threaded. i have submitted a bug report.  i could probably modify the source so it doesnt call 'pjsip show endpoints' on startup which causes the crash, then all good!

Comment: pjsip have similar amount of bugs and developed not for asterisk. As result configs and realtime still work strange. If your load allow use chan_sip, use it instead of pjsip.

Answer (score 0):

i have configured my asterisk in proxy mode with no registration peer with following configuration

```
[transport-udp] 
type=transport protocol=udp             ;
bind=0.0.0.0
context=default                         ; to be returned as device state (default: "0") 
t38_udptl=yes                           ; Whether T 38 UDPTL support is enabled or not (default: "no") 
t38_udptl_ec=none                       ; T 38 UDPTL error correction method (default: "none") 
t38_udptl_maxdatagram=0                 ; T 38 UDPTL maximum datagram size (default:; "0") 
fax_detect=no                           ; Whether CNG tone detection is enabled (default: "no") 
fax_detect_timeout=30
```

when i make a call with prxoy mode i got following error on asterisk console

> [Dec  4 12:37:53] ERROR[5116]: chan_pjsip.c:2205 request: Unable to
>   create PJSIP channel with empty endpoint name